# SqlDataReader is drops columns randomly!

Tags: .net, asp.net, sqldatareader

I have a very strange issue, I'm using `System.Data.SqlClient`.
 to get data from a SQL Server though a stored procedure. 
When I test the Application at the Development and Stagging machines it works fine but when I deploy the application on the **Production Server** I **randomly** getting an `SqlDataReader` `IndexOutOfRangeException` with different column names!.

*The error appears in 2 requests in each 1000 request (approximative).*

*The SQL Server is Clustered*

Source Code:

```
public static List<CountryInfo> GetAllCountries(){
            List<CountryInfo> Items = new List<CountryInfo>();
            try{
                using (rdr = SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(Globals.ConnectionString, "unv_spGetAllCountries"))
                {
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        CountryInfo item = new CountryInfo();
                        item.CountryId = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["CountryId"]);
                        item.CountryName = rdr["CountryName"].ToString();
                        item.FirstLevel = rdr["FirstLevel"].ToString();
                        item.SecondLevel = rdr["SecondLevel"].ToString();

                        Items.Add(item);

                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

            Items.TrimExcess();
            return Items;
        }
```

Stored Procedure:

```
select * from unv_tblCountries order by CountryName;
```

**Already Tested**

- Check Stored Procedure column names.
- Check Reader Column names.
- Check connection String.

Anyone faced like this issue and solve it?

Comment: You'll have to provide more details and preferably the relevant source. Without it, there's little to say about it.

Comment: I suggest a catch block that will log this exception and all passed in parameters.

Comment: I have added more information.

Comment: `select * ...` is not going to help you, if `unv_tblCountries` changes (or is different in different instances) you'll get errors at a distance rather than within the query itself -- this makes debugging harder. Thus `select *` in production code is generally regarded as poor form (ad-hoc queries are different).

Comment: @Richad I added the columns to the select statement but still the issue not solved :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it the `SqlDataReader` varibale `rdr` was declared as `static` in the controllers **base class** which maked it a shared varibale between all the controllers. The requests threads were using the same `DataReader` and changing the columns in it.

Answer (score 3):

I'll wager this is not a data-reader issue. My guess would be that one or more user accounts is using a more-specific (and older) copy of the sproc (etc) - for example Fred.MyProc instead of dbo.MyProc, or there is conditional branching logic in the sproc that returns different columns in some cases - maybe a branch of code you forgot to update.

Another potential issue is perhaps different case-sensitivity in the DB causin different objects to be used; i.e. Myproc vs MyProc - which can be different if the DB is case-sensitive.

To find out for sure, attach a SQL trace to log **exactly** what (and by whom) is sent for the failing cases; then repro that in something like SSMS, comparing dev to prod.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I modified the connection string to connect to the live database with the same username and password and it was working fine the issue is when deploying the app on the production servers!

Comment: @Khaled then your prod server isn't configured the same, or there is a branch of code that is only reached with he data in prod; you will have to try to repro it and trace it, to see what.

Comment: Thanks for your corporation ,  I have a doubt in the server and network, BTW which configuration you meant?